# Latex header problem

Tags: header-footer

I have a problem with my header. I set header like :

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chead{\scriptsize{\textit{Proc. of the $19^{th}$ Int. Conference on Digital Audio Effects (DAFx-16), Brno, Czech republic, September, 2016}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
```

and averything is OK, but at pages below my table of content appear another header. I dont know how to set it correct, can somebody help me please ?

[image: pic from LC]
<sub>(source: [latex-community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/download/file.php?id=8511))</sub>

Comment: I think there is a extra word "content" in header

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is needed.

Comment: This is a crosspost to [LaTeX-community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=26318&view=unread#unread).

Comment: `\fancyhead{}` before setting `\chead`.

Comment: `LaTeX header` is misleading, in my point of view. The title should be changed to `Page header problem`

Comment: @Johannes_B Cross-posting on external sites is not really an issue, by the way.

Comment: @Alenanno According to the rules of LC, a crosspost has to be marked as such. That is what i did.

Comment: @Johannes_B I'm not sure I understand: you're saying the rules on LC say you need to mark a crosspost, posting a comment on the other sites? Anyway, I was just meaning to say that cross-posting is usually an issue within the SE network, but maybe your comment was not posted in that sense.

Comment: @Alenanno Section 4.1 in http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5838 A user should always link both threads/questions against each other. How many sites do you frequent? My max was the same question posted on three different sites within 15 minutes, which leads us to [Gimme Pizza](http://www.latex-community.org/home/latex-community/94-etiquette/454-crossposts).

Comment: @Johannes_B Sites about Latex? Only this one. :)

Comment: @Alenanno By the way, i just remembered [Is cross-site posting allowed officially?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4187)

Answer (score 2):

From my [answer at LaTeX-community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=89940#p89940):

> You need to clear the header before getting new material in there. Use `\fancyhead{}` to clear it, set the `\chead` later.

Comment: What would a complete LaTeX file look like if the LaTeX file contained the corrected (edited or remedied) code?